# Não consigo implementar os valores do ArrayList na tabela no JSP file

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

Eu estou iniciando no conteúdo de Java Web e fiquei preso na seguinte situação:

estou tentando transferir os valores da ArrayList criados dentro do JSP file para a tabela que se encontra dentro do JSP file também; porém não consigo fazer a iteração desses valores para dentro da tabela. Eu estou criando o código no Eclipse, pois foi a IDE que eu mais me identifiquei, porém o professor deu o conteúdo no Netbeans.

Não sei se o código está errado porque a sintaxe nas IDE é diferente. Além disso, o professor fez pouco caso da minha dúvida, talvez por não saber mexer no Eclipse ou por que não quis ajudar mesmo, e estou precisando de ajuda para poder prosseguir com o conteúdo. O código segue abaixo:

```
<%@page import=java.util.ArrayList %>
<%@page import=escola.Aluno %>

<table border="">

    <tr>
        <th><b>ID</b></th>
        <th><b>Nome</b></th>
        <th><b>Série</b></th>
    </tr>

    <%
        ArrayList<Aluno> alunos = new ArrayList<Aluno>();

        alunos.add(new Aluno(1, "Hugo", "1º ano/médio"));
        alunos.add(new Aluno(2, "José", "2º ano/médio"));

        for (Aluno al : alunos) {


            out.println("<tr>");
            out.println("<td>" + al.getId() + "</td>");
            out.println("<td>" + al.getNome() + "</td>");
            out.println("<td>" + al.getSerie() + "</td>");
            out.println("</tr>");

        }
    %>

</table>
```

O código e os valores saem todos impressos em linha acima do esqueleto da tabela criada (ID, Nome e Série). Eu possuo essa classe Aluno com o construtor contendo os elementos nessa ordem da criação do ArrayList.

Comment: Ocorre algum erro no console do seu servidor? Alerto para utilização de scriptlets(código java junto com html) como uma má prática.

Comment: O problema estava na ausência das aspas na importação do ArrayList e da classe Aluno. Acabei de ler hoje sobre essa má prática haha creio que o professor só fez desse modo para apresentar o jsp, mas obrigado pela dica!